# regex string followed by a number php string replace

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I'm not great with regex and I am trying to search a string for "&option=" plus a number [0-100].

So far i have this :

```
$link = str_replace("^&option[0-9]"," ",$actual_link);
```

Can any one help me with the correct regex expression?

Comment: It would be `preg_replace` as opposed to `str_replace`

Comment: perfect thank you haha such a simple fix +1 if you could on a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever its `$` or `&` (confused by your question), use `preg_replace()` for your regex replace.

```
$link = preg_replace("/[&$]option=(?:100|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b/"," ",$actual_link);
```

And I don't think you need that `^` for the anchoring!

Comment: edited my question too many variables have been written this day. thank you

Comment: @andrewhutchings it doesn't matter. It handles both. If you need to remove `$`, just erase from there!